# open desktop using QText Browser

Tags: c++, qt

Right now I am displaying something like /home/binary/ in QText browser. Now I want the open the folder by clicking on this text. How to do that ? Thanks in advance

Here is my sample code. I am display the result
s

> ```
> bool MainWindow::displayResult(multimap<string,
> ```
>
> string> &resultMap, string &filePath)
>       {
>           multimap::iterator iter;
>           bool fileStatus = false;
>           int noOfLocFound = 0, forAppending = 0;
>           QString no;
>
> ```
>     noOfLocFound = resultMap.size();
>
>     if ( noOfLocFound != 0 )
>         ui->textBrowser->append( "<i>File found at <b>" + no.setNum (
> ```
>
> noOfLocFound ) + " locations");
>
> ```
>     for ( forAppending = 0,iter = resultMap.begin(); iter !=
> ```
>
> resultMap.end(); iter++,
>   forAppending++ )
>           {
>               string file = iter->first;
>               string dir = iter->second;
>
> ```
>         if ( forAppending == 0)
>             filePath.append(dir);
>         else
>             filePath.append(","+dir);
>
>         QString qdir = QString::fromStdString(dir);
>
>         cout << "Display";
>
>         ui->textBrowser->append( qdir );
>         fileStatus = true;
>
>     }
>
>     if ( fileStatus == false )
>     {
>         ui->textBrowser->append("File not
> ```
>
> found");
>               return false;
>           }
>
> ```
>     return true;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

By "open the folder", do you mean, open a file dialog for the user to select something inside of the given directory?

If so, you would probably want to connect your QTextBrowser's clicked signal to a slot that looked something like:

```
// connect events, in MyWindow constructor, or whereever...
connect(textbrowser, SIGNAL(mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)), this, SLOT(openFileDialog(QMouseEvent*)));

void MyWindow::openFileDialog(QMouseEvent* event) {
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    QStringList files = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, "Select a file...",
        textbrowser.plainText());

    // do something with the files here...
}
```

Comment: Let me put my question in another way ---- Rite now I am displaying the result in QText Browser. Results will be something like /home/User/ , /media/Arena/ etc. Now I want to open this folders by clicking on this result which is displayed in QText Browser. But I dnt have any idea how to do that. In one of the thread someone ask me to use anchor clicked but I dnt know how to use it. So can you please give me piece of code on how to do it. Tanx in advance. P.S I am using QT creato

Comment: Maybe if you post some of your existing code it'd be easy to see what to want to accomplish?